# Creating a method that executes every x seconds

Tags: java, android, eclipse, time

So I am trying to make an alarm clock/ quiz game app for android with java. I have a method right now that plays a sound sequence, but I need this method to be called every `x seconds` (or in some repeatable fashion) until a condition is met.

I would like to post my attempt, but I have absolutely no idea how I would go about doing this other than maybe sticking a bunch of code in a while statement which seems really ugly.

Comment: [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
new Handler().postDelayed(runnable, delayMillis)
```

from with in the method and call it again

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [java.util.Timer](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) which will allow you to schedule a `TimerTask` on a specified interval.   It's easy to subclass `TimerTask` to do whatever you want.  You can then schedule many different tasks right off the bat on regular intervals, or you can schedule a single task, and then delegate to that Task scheduling the next one, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

```
Timer myTimer = new Timer();

myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask(){
  @Override
  public void Run(){

     // your task to be executed here

  }
}, 0, x*1000);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html